Issues with Streaming HTML Content in JavaScript: Leading Parts of Tags Getting Removed
I’m working on a project where I need to stream HTML content from a server to a client using Server-Sent Events (SSE). The server sends chunks of HTML content that should be displayed on the client side in real-time. However, I’m facing an issue where leading parts of HTML tags, such as <h and <p, are getting removed during the rendering process on the client side.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Server-Side PHP Code:
The server sends chunks of HTML content using SSE.
Each chunk is processed and sent to the client.
PHP code snippet which acts as a proxy between Open API chat completion API and my client.
function process_openai_stream_data($data, &$full_response) {
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        return 0; // Stop the stream if the client has disconnected
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $data);
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        if (strpos($line, 'data: ') === 0) {
            $line = trim(substr($line, 6)); // Remove 'data: ' prefix
            if ($line === '[DONE]') {
                // End of stream signal
                echo "data: [END]\n\n";
                flush();
                return 0; // Stop the stream
            }
            $json = json_decode($line, true);
            if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
                continue;
            }
            if (isset($json['choices'][0]['delta']['content'])) {
                $content = $json['choices'][0]['delta']['content'];
                $full_response .= $content;
                echo "data: " . $content . "\n\n";
                flush();
            }
        }
    }
    return strlen($data);
}

Client-Side JavaScript Code:
The client receives the data and appends it to a div.
javascript code which processes the events:
function downloadResults(requestId) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('action', 'download_feedback_streaming');
    formData.append('request_id', requestId);
    formData.append('nonce', beyond.nonce);
    formData.append('ajax', 'frontend');

    const resultDisplay = document.getElementById('result-content');
    if (!resultDisplay) {
        console.error('Result display element not found');
        return;
    }
    resultDisplay.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content

    fetch(beyond.ajaxurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const decoder = new TextDecoder();
        let buffer = '';

        function readStream() {
            reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
                if (done) {
                    displayAudioFeedback();
                    console.log('Stream complete');
                    return;
                }

                buffer += decoder.decode(value, { stream: true });
                const events = buffer.split('\n\n');
                buffer = events.pop(); // Keep the last incomplete event in the buffer

                events.forEach(event => {
                    if (event.startsWith('data: ')) {
                        const data = event.slice(6); // Remove 'data: ' prefix
                        // Append to the result display
                        resultDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data);
                    }
                });

                readStream(); // Continue reading next chunk
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error reading stream:', error);
                displayError("An error occurred while retrieving your feedback. Please try again.");
            });
        }

        readStream(); // Start reading the stream
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error downloading results:', error);
        displayError("An error occurred while retrieving your feedback. Please try again.");
    });
}

The Issue:
When streaming, some HTML tags are split across chunks, resulting in the leading parts of the tags getting removed. For instance:
The tag  might be split into <h, 3, and >, and I see that the <h in this example is not getting added to the div. This happens for other tags such as <p as well.
What I’ve Tried:
I printed the data on the server side, during the API invocation from the client and the Javascript code. The data is coming as expected in the first two places. I noticed a new line added to the closing tag such as “>n”.
[07-Jul-2024 22:20:35 UTC] data: {"id":"chatcmpl-9iUXCKCHUnVncnVOWUOP8W9I8cqOE","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1720390834,"model":"gpt-4-0613","system_fingerprint":null,"choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":">\n"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

On the Javascript side, the opening portion of the tag that comes right after the closing tag with the new line is getting ignored.
Question:
How can I ensure that HTML tags split across multiple chunks are correctly handled and displayed on the client? Is there a better way to handle this if I want to display HTML-formatted content to the user?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

If you can't prevent this in the place where the data is getting chunked like this, then I suppose you can only implement a mechanism on the client side that "waits" until you received enough data for a complete HTML tag, and only then inserts it into the document.

Yes, that' one option. I was wondering if there is a better option.
